# How to export virtual machine from fedora gnome-boxes to virtual box

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, fedora, gnome

I would like to know whether is possible export all configuration, files, programs, etc of my virtual machine in `gnome-boxes` app and then import it to a **Windows 10** with `virtual box` app

I have see this  [question](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/29704/how-do-i-move-a-virtual-machine-in-gnome-boxes-to-another-host/)  but only works in the same system fedora.

My fedora versión is `fedora28`

Comment: You don't need to export, but to convert the volumes of the virtual-machine into a format that virtualbox understands. gnome-boxes is a front-end for libvirtd, which uses qemu-kvm, so check your `$HOME/.local/share/gnome-boxes/images` for image files, and run `qemu-img convert -O vdi original.img converted.vdi`. Just copy the vdi to windows and load into virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to export and import files, but rather convert the disk between gnome-boxes and VirtualBox formats.

First, you need to find the image file you want to convert:

```bash
ls ~/.local/share/gnome-boxes/images
```

Second, (as @guido points out), You should be good with [manually converting](https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/convert-images.html) the disk file to [VDI](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/user/vdidetails.html):

```bash
# assuming the right image name is ubuntu22.04 (the -p option is for progress bar)
qemu-img convert -pO vdi ubuntu22.04 ubuntu22.04-converted.vdi
```

Third, you continue by creating a [VirtualBox machine Using the existing VDI file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/524803/448375)